# Merge [applications] and [applying] tags; should we go for it?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Recently it came to my attention that we have both [applications](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) and [applying](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applying) tags.

The first one has currently 676 questions and a brief excerpt, but the other one has only 38 posts and lacks an excerpt and wiki.

As I see it, having both tags seems redundant; it would seem adequate to keep only [applications](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) tag. Also, having both tags is confusing, and results in misuse of such (currently, I see that the tags are used arbitrarily and even both at the same time).

**Should we proceed to retag/merge [applying](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applying) to [applications](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications)?** If we reach a consensus I can gladly do the re-tagging.

An alternative I can think is to make a *synonym*, so [applying](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applying) points to [applications](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications). In that case, we would require to reach consensus and to propose and vote on the [synonimization](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/applications/synonyms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Support**. Seems like an obvious synonym. Note that there are [automated systems in place for a community-led synonym to be created](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) but not for merges. If consensus here is positive just flag this question for moderator attention though I expect one of us will get around to this when they see it later.

---

EDIT This is now done. Not too much visibility on this question but no negative responses so that's consensus to me.

> updating post history, 43 rows affected (pipe delimited)
>
> updating posts, 38 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
>
> updating PostTags associations, 22 rows affected
>
> destroying 'applying': [applying] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
>
> total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
>
> 0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
>
> 0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
>
> updating count for target tag, new count: 699
>
> tag remapping of [applications] and [applying] complete!
>
> remapping 0 synonyms
>
> 1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
>
> 0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
>
> Deleting Synonym applying -> job-search
>
> Tag Synonym applying -> applications was approved!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, please do this! I had [previously submitted a synonym request](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) to map [applying](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applying) to [job-search](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-search) before realizing that [applications](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) was a better fit. If we do this via community rather than moderators, I think that synonym will need to first be down-voted so it can be removed.

Comment: That synonym was deleted as part of the merge (log on my answer).